# Join two queries where one is grouped

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm creating simple PHP / Laravel app and I have reached a problem:
I need to somehow join 2 queries, but I am not sure how to.
I could do it with some messy PHP loops, but I know that's not the right approach.

my queries in Laravel's code looks:

```
$cars = Car::get();
$drives = Drive::select(DB::raw('car_id, max(odometer) as odometer'))->groupBy('car_id')->get();
```

in plain SQL something like:

```
$cars = 'SELECT * FROM cars';
$drives = 'SELECT car_id, max(odometer) as odometer FROM drive GROUP BY car_id';
```

> (drive)'car_id' = (cars)'id'

**Update:** Forgot to mention: I have 'odometer' field in 'car' and get max('odometer') from drives, so if there is something returned from 'drives' it should overwrite the one returned from 'car'

DRIVE:

```
id
car_id
user_id
odometer
liters_filled
route
is_private
is_refill
is_full
checque
date
deleted_at
created_at
updated_at
```

CARS:

```
id
title
plate_number
year
tank_size
odometer
user_id
deleted_at
created_at
updated_at
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: when something is getting complicated, its probably not worth it or wrong. why not just write plain sql with a join clause instead of fighting the orm? will probably give the best performance while not loosing much (you can even pull the table names from the orm

Comment: @BenYitzhaki I'm not sure how to do that, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I'm not 100% on what you are asking but you could try the following:

```
SELECT  cr.id ,
        dr.oodometer

FROM Car cr
INNER JOIN (SELECT dr.car_id,MAX(dr.oodometer) AS oodometer
           FROM Drive dr
           GROUP BY car_id ) dr ON dr.car_id = cr.id
```

Comment: I get: Unknown column 'cr.car_id' in 'field list'

Comment: what are the keys in the two tables?

Comment: Added to my Question

Comment: It's almost working as I need (I changed to LEFT JOIN), but only problem is that now it returns null where max() returns nothing

Comment: If you have to use left join, I'm unsure why, you will have to specify WHERE oodometer IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cars.*, max(driver.oodometer) as odometer FROM cars
INNER JOIN driver on cars.id=driver.car_id
group by driver.car_id
```

This query will join the 2 tables for you and get you the info. The table names i used are your variable names for the sake of the example.

Edit for Laravel:

In *config/database.php* at *mysql* change :

```
'strict' => true,
```

to `false`.

Comment: doesn't work because everything that is selected under '*' is not in group by statement

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'gas_tracking.cars.id' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: @Sinto that's just a name of my DB

Comment: I think this is a laravel problem check my post again